# Proposal to merge "salat" tag with "salah" tag

Tags: discussion, tag

I propose to merge the "salat" tag with the "salah" tag.
If I am correct, they are the same thing and should be merged.

Comment: +1 we should also set it as a synonym

Answer (score 7):

Done and done.  [salah](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/salah) is now synonymed and merged with [salat](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/salat).